# Flutter routes in combination with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, routes, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I'm working on a web app and have a question about routing.
How do you route in combination with Firebase Auth?

On the internet I see a lot of examples with a AuthenticationWrapper.
If you are logged in you are going to the home page and if you are not logged in you are going to the Sign in page.
That part works. But in the app I want to make more routes.

I learned (Example 1 below) that you can make routes in MaterialApp. I have
tried to make this work but it didn't.

How can I route in combination with Firebase Auth and when a user is not logged in it navigates to the Sign in page?

I would love to hear your input on this issue. Thanks in advance!

**Main.dart:**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<AuthenticationService>(
            create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
          ),
          StreamProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
          )
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Name of the app', 
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            ),
            home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
        ));
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      // Page after loggin in
      return HomePage(); 
    }
    // Sign in page
    return SignInPage();
  }
}
```

**Example 1:**

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
  // on the FirstScreen widget.
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little more? (How can I route in combination with Firebase Auth and when a user is not logged in it navigates to the Sign in page?)

Comment: When you go to a page where you needs to have an account. But you are not logged in that it redirect to the sign in page. (First login and then watch the content)

Comment: And I want to know how you can make multiple routes and every time it checks if the user is logged in.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is create a custom function with all the possibilities you want in your app like this and call the specific function when you wanna check the status of user

```
void _check(String username) {
      if(user has account) {
        if(loggedin) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Home.id);
        } else { //if not logged in
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, SignIn.id);
        }
      } else { // if dont have account
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, SignUP.id);
      }
}
```